# What are smtplib.ehlo() and smtplib.helo()

Tags: python

I'm learning Python and looking at the smtplib module.

I have seen several code examples, and many have `smtplib.ehlo()` or `smtplib.helo()`

What do they mean? What are they for?

Comment: I understand the function, what I don't understand is when it is necessary to use the function

Comment: Do you know the SMTP protocol?

Answer (score 3):

You really need to read the RFC that defines SMTP, which is  https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5321 .  `HELO` was the original introductory command (in RFC 821, in 1982!).  Eventually, extensions were added that were not backward compatible.  To say that you wanted to use the extension, you'd use `EHLO`.  `EHLO` is now recommended for every SMTP transaction.